# Getting API authentication key error with PublicAPI

Tags: javascript, api, public

I'm new to the FetchAPAI. For my first API project, I'm currently using the ClimatIQ API and following the steps in their Quickstart [guide](https://docs.climatiq.io/guides/quickstart). Even if I've already signed up and received an authentication key from them, I keep getting the ff error from them:

```
POST https://beta2.api.climatiq.io/estimate 400
{error: 'invalid_request', message: 'Error parsing the request body.'}
```

Take note in the guide, the code is in Curl, and I did my best trying to convert that code into a fetchAPI request on JavaScript.

```
const fetchData = async (url) => {
  await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer MY_API_KEY" },
    data: {
      emission_factor: "electricity-energy_source_grid_mix",
      parameters: {
        energy: 4200,
        energy_unit: "kWh",
      },
    },
    //body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((err) => console.log(`Here's the error ${err}`));
};

fetchData("https://beta2.api.climatiq.io/estimate");
```

From time to time, it also shows a "header is not defined" even if I already put in the authentication key they gave me in the "MY_API_KEY" part of my codebase. Is this an error with their server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const data = {
  emission_factor: "electricity-energy_source_grid_mix",
  parameters: {
    energy: 4200,
    energy_unit: "kWh",
  },
};

const fetchData = async(url) => {
  await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer MY_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((err) => console.log(`Here's the error ${err}`));
};

fetchData("https://beta2.api.climatiq.io/estimate");
```

Comment: You're absolutely amazing! Thank you so much. I really need to grind it out with that header section and internalize it in my head from now on. :-/